# Moving NPM project to Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, npm

I have a simple example project I was able to run by

1. Installing Node.js for windows x64
2. Git clone https://github.com/BretCameron/three-js-sample.git
3. Running

   npm install react-scripts

   npm audit-fix

   npm start

This started a `localhost:3000` server that I can view the example on, and it works

Now I want to put this whole web app on a local apache server, for which I am using XAMPP. And eventually I want to put it on a server online.

I am used to doing this with a PHP app like Wordpress,
Where you put all the project files into the htdocs folder.

I assume to do this I would need to get all of the Node.js files and put them in the same directory? Is that how this works?
I can't even seem to find where npm installed `react-scripts`

Can someone please describe how to get the application from running a built in local server with `npm start` to an application hosted on an online server.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `npm start` runs a local server so you can develop your files by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:3000`. When you're done developing, you can run a script, something like `npm build` to compile your JS files into a finalized bundle ready to be delivered to your audience. This is the difference between development code and production code. You can then upload that bundled JS file to your `htdocs` folder so the Apache server can deliver the finalized file to your visitors.

You shouldn't try running node in Apache. I don't think it's possible, and if it is, it would be pretty difficult to set up for no purpose. There's no reason to run a node server that's constantly checking JS files for updates to constantly serve development code. You want to package it into production code once, and then just serve that single file.

The script to bundle your code varies from project to project. Check out your `package.json` file, you should see a `scripts` section like the screenshot below. In this example, running `npm run dev` serves the code in development mode through `localhost`, and `npm run build` compiles my JavaScript into a bundle ready to upload for production.

[image]

Good luck!